# Jumbotron padding of Bootstrap overriding my CSS

Tags: css

The image in jumbotron has spaces all around. When I reduce the padding in CSS, it is being overridden by Bootstrap CSS.
  !important is not working. My CSS file is after the Bootstrap CSS.
  Trying out a lot on this!
 Please help!

Thanks in advance

**HTML PART:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<body>
<header>
    --- NAVBAR PART
</header>

<div id="main-content" class="container">
<div class="jumbotron">
    <img src="images/jumb1.jpg" alt="Pic1" class="img-responsive center-block">
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.jumbotron {
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you open browser's element inspector, you can see what exactly overrides your CSS rules and how to avoid it. So, if you see something like this being written in bootstrap.css:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.jumbotron {
  padding: 48px 0;
}
```

In order to overwrite it, you should use a media query as well. For example:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.jumbotron {
  padding: 20px 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But that too is not working. Tried that as well. But I only see the Bootstrap css on Inspect element.     Added the following piece of code in CSS: @media screen and (min-width: 768px){
 .container .jumbotron {
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

Comment: The padding in bootstrap css is inside both container and container-fluid class:                                                                                                    @media screen and (min-width: 768px)
.container .jumbotron, .container-fluid .jumbotron {
    padding-right: 60px;
    padding-left: 60px;                                                                                   }                                                                                                                I tried incluing those containers in custom css. But it's the same result.

Comment: Please provide a live example of your issue so I could help you